# Start menu for Raspberry?

Tags: raspbian, boot, terminal

I want to have a start menu for raspbian, which comes up after boot into console, where I can choose what to start: Console, GUI, Emulation Station or a media player like xmbc.

This could be a script with options like the raspi-config, or a little graphical tool.

Searched for something like that, but found nothing useful.

Any hints?

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: DIY? raspi-config is a shell script that uses whiptail for the menu, Source is available at https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config. I'm sure there are many examples for whiptail available

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a bunch of Systemd targets. You already have `graphical.target` for GUI and `multi-user.target` for the console, so write two more, e.g. `emulation.target` and `mediacenter.target`. You could probably find good examples of such target files in OpenELEC / RetroPi projects.

Then make another target, e.g. `menu.target`, which would be the default one and would run your menu script. You can make a text-based menu in plain bash, use `dialog` or a GUI tool like `yad` or `zenity` to make a GUI menu. [Here](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps)'s an example of a GUI you can do with `yad`. The core of the script would be

```
target = $(dialog --title "Start menu" --menu "Choose a target" 25 78 10 \
"multi-user.target" "Console" \
"graphical.target" "Desktop" \
"emulation.target" "Retro Games" \
"mediacenter.target" "XMBC")
systemctl isolate $target
```

You would still be able to boot into any target from command line using `systemctl`:

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

Comment: Might be worth be worth mentioning for those who read the man page `isolate UNIT` (which is explicitly documented there) != "isolate TARGET", which is what this is (and that's fine).  For those that don't read it and think to apply this to a single *service*: You should read that first...